# Are webservice sessions specific to the consumer or it gets global across all consumers?

Tags: .net, web-services, session

We are using webservices with session enabled.

Just wanted to know if the session is across all consumers or current consumer?

What I mean to ask is that:- Is it like ASP.NET session state (which is user specific) or like ASP.NET application state (which is across all users of application)?

On which server is the state managed. Web service server or consumer server?

Comment: I guess you enabled session with WebMethod(EnableSession=true) then yes, it's _not like_ ASP.NET session state but _it is_ ASP.NET session state.

Comment: On which server is the state managed. Web service server or consumer server?

Comment: Session is managed on web server. Usually through a token (cookie or URL parameter) kept in the consumer.

Comment: which server: Web service host server or consumer server??

Answer (score 0):

I haven't noticed any difference in using session in Webservice or in webforms. The values stored are definitely session scoped and not application scoped. You should be able to confirm this by accessing your page (which uses the service) from two different browser windows.

Comment: On which server is the state managed. Web service server or consumer server?

Comment: I agree with @adriano, sessions can be managed only at the Web Service server..more over, services can be called from client scripts as well..